# Save dynamic data to a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0

How can I save data to the multidimensional array 'dataS' properly?

```
string servicios = getTextServicios();

// here an example for servicios value could be:
//"1==11==111\n2==22==222\n3==33==333"
//but the number of rows (\n) is dynamic

string[] lineas = Regex.Split(servicios, "\n");
string[] sublineas;

String[][] dataS = {};

foreach (string linea in lineas)
{
   sublineas = Regex.Split(linea, "==");
   //I want to add the lines to the array but I don't know how
   dataS += new String[]{sublineas[0], sublineas[1], sublineas[2]},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] lineas = Regex.Split(servicios, "\n");
string[] sublineas;

String[][] dataS = new string[lineas.Length][];

for(int i=0; i<lineas.Length;i++)
{
    dataS[i] = Regex.Split(lineas[i], "==");
}
```

Also, consider writing your code in english. It's a good habbit.